# Go & Javascript secure authentication

Tags: javascript, go, authentication

I'm currently signing users (authenticating) from the frontend, and making requests to the backend to sign up the user(save data in the database). I realize i cannot completely prevent this, but i don't want my API(signup) to be abused.

Go:

```
func SignIn(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    params := mux.Vars(r)
    u_ip := base64Decode((params["u_ip"]))
    u_wallet := base64Decode(string(params["u_wallet"]))
    u_password := base64Decode(params["u_pass"])

    u_addr := strings.TrimPrefix(u_wallet, "0x")
    u_addr_temp := u_addr[0:7]
    for rowExists("select 1 from users where position(user_addr in $1)>0", u_addr_temp) {
        randInt := rand.Intn(5)
        u_addr_temp = u_addr[randInt : randInt+7]
    }

    sqlStatement := `INSERT INTO users (ip, user_addr, user_wallet, user_pass)
     VALUES($1, $2, $3, $4) returning id;`
    id := 0
    db := opendb()
    err := db.QueryRow(sqlStatement, u_ip, u_addr_temp, u_wallet, u_password).Scan(&id)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusCreated)
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    resp := make(map[string]string)
    resp["message"] = string(id) + "-" + string(u_addr_temp)
    jsonResp, err := json.Marshal(resp)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Json Err. Err: %s", err)
    }
    w.Write(jsonResp)
}
```

Javascript:

```
              const u_wallet = window.btoa(result);
              const u_password = window.btoa(password.toString());
              await fetch(
                `http://localhost:8080/sign/${u_wallet}&${u_password}`,
                {
                  method: "POST",
                }
              )
                .then((response) => response.json())
                .then((data) => console.log(data));
            })();
```

You can see users can call `http://localhost:8080/sign/${u_wallet}&${u_password}` replace the wallet, and password (Base64 encoded) And GoLang will automatically create the row(in the database).

Go CORS:

```
    c := cors.New(cors.Options{
        AllowedOrigins:   []string{"*"},
        AllowCredentials: true,
    })
    handler := c.Handler(router)
```

I can define Allowed Origins as strict-origin-when-cross-origin, but users will use the devtools console(JS).
**My question isn't sending the data(safely), but how to communicate from the frontend and backend, and try and block users from calling the API.**